# Angular2: change border color for error in form validation

Tags: html, css, angular

Trying to change the border color for error message. this is my html code

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Name:</label>
  <div class="wpr">
    <div class="wpr__icon">
      <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    </div>
    <input #name="ngModel" id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control text-line" [(ngModel)]="PersonInfo.name"
      pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+" required>
  </div>
  <ul class="alert-error" *ngIf="name.touched && name.errors">
    <li *ngIf="name.errors.required"> Name is required. </li>
    <li *ngIf="name.errors.pattern">Invalid name.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Currently error messages are showing up, but I want to change the textbox border-color to red. How to do that.

Comment: did you try it in the browser?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `ngClass` directive to add css class to your input field when it is invalid:

```
<input #name="ngModel" id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control text-line"
[ngClass]="{'red-border-class': name.errors}" [(ngModel)]="PersonInfo.name" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+" required>
```

Hope you don't need help writing css. :-)

Answer (score 28):

Here is another solution.

```
input.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

If you inspect your input field, you can see some css classes that Angular dynamically attach to your element that you can take advantage of.

Comment: .ng-touched class makes it more cool, as on initial form load, the text boxes aren't shown as red. Only when they are 'touched', they become red if invalid

Answer (score 1):

Just find **.alert-error class in css file** and add **border property**.

```
.alert-error{
   ...
   border:1px solid red;
   color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve different ways, but I personally preferred the following way.

**HTML**

```
<form [ngClass]="{ 'form-submit': isSubmit}" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" name="forgotPasswordForm" [formGroup]="forgotPasswordForm">                
  <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" formControlName="email">
  <div class="invalid-feedback form-error" *ngIf="...">
    .......
  </div>  
 </form>
```

**CSS:**

```
.form-group input.ng-invalid.ng-touched, 
.form-group input.ng-invalid:focus, 
.form-group select.ng-invalid.ng-touched, 
.form-group textarea.ng-invalid.ng-touched,
.form-submit input.ng-invalid,
.form-submit select.ng-invalid,
.form-submit  textarea.ng-invalid
{
    border-color: #ff4c6a;
}

.invalid-feedback.form-error {
    display: block;
}
```