# how to clear red border of textbox in html form using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, html

I have a form that looks like this:

[image: Form]

When I click on submit button it shows red border on textbox fields because of required attribute.

After that I want to click reset button, then it should clear the red border of the textbox.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Post the code please

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39764299/angular2-change-border-color-for-error-in-form-validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form you have something like this:

```
<form name="vm.myForm">
```

Your reset should be one of these:

```
<input type="reset" />
<button></button>
```

You can tie the ng-click on the button to a method in your controller:

```
<input ng-click="vm.resetForm()" />
<button ng-click="vm.resetForm()"></button>
```

Then in your controller:

```
resetForm() {
  this.myForm.$setPristine();
}
```

That should reset the form to a pristine state, and remove any red borders caused by an invalid form (ie required inputs not filled in).

Comment: Thanks for your help